# How to draw bell curve of SD over a histogram in R?

Tags: r, histogram, standard-deviation

i'm trying to figure out how to visualize the standard deviation over histogram of Age. In **CODE 1** a histogram of Age over frequency is provided. Please note that the frequency represents the number of people in the histogram (i.e. around 550 people are at age between 70-75). However the way i want to visualize it is provided **CODE 2**, but notice that the histogram displays the density instead of frequency. When i try to **CODE 3**, the line of the bell-curve is flat. Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

**CODE 1:**

```
#PROVIDE HISTOGRAMS OF AGE AND TOTAL.DAYS.IN.HOSPITAL
hist(
  dataset15$Age, las=1,
  main="Histogram of Age", xlab="AGE", ylab="Number of patients",
  xlim = c(0,100), ylim = c(0,600),
  xaxp = c(0,100,10), yaxp=c(0,600,24)
)
```

**CODE 2:**

```
hist(dataset15$Age, freq=F, breaks=12)
lines(
  seq(10, 100, by=.5), 
  dnorm(seq(10, 100, by=.5),
  mean(dataset15$Age), 
  sd(dataset15$Age)), 
  col="blue"
)
```

**CODE 3:**

```
#PROVIDE HISTOGRAMS OF AGE AND TOTAL.DAYS.IN.HOSPITAL
hist(
  dataset15$Age, las=1,
  main="Histogram of Age", xlab="AGE", ylab="Number of patients",
  xlim = c(0,100), ylim = c(0,600),
  xaxp = c(0,100,10), yaxp=c(0,600,24)
)
lines(
  seq(0, 100, by=.5), 
  dnorm(seq(0, 100, by=.5),
  mean(dataset15$Age), sd(dataset15$Age)), 
  col="blue"
)
```

**OUTPUT 1:**
[image: FIGURE 1]

**OUTPUT 2:**
[image: FIGURE 2]

**OUTPUT 3:**
[image: FIGURE 3]

Comment: You can multiply the result of `dnorm` by the ratio between the two maximum values (550/0.04 or something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Rodrigo, you have to scale the density to your histogram.
See my code below.

```
n <- 2000
age <- rnorm(n, m = 70, sd = 5)


h <- hist(age,
          las=1, breaks = 20,
          main="Histogram of Age", xlab="AGE", ylab="Number of patients",
     xlim = c(0,100), ylim = c(0,600),
     xaxp = c(0,100,10), yaxp=c(0,600,24))

lx <- seq(10, 100, by=.5)
ly <- dnorm(lx, mean(age), sd(age)) * sum(h$counts)/sum(h$density), # here is the magic
lines(x = lx,y = ly,col ="blue")
```

Outputs the following plot :

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, i really appreciate your answer. Quick, easy and understandable.